# Pokemon keep running away and Pokestops don't drop anything when spinning. What is going on?

Tags: pokemon-go

I can't do anything now. Can't catch Pokemon, can't get items. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: The current top-voted answer in this meta post, [On ending Chronological Oppression with respect to the matter of Question Duplication](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8190/4797) -  suggests that the first question with a definitively upvoted answer should be made the original, and the others duped to it. i.e. The duplicate closure to [Why can't I catch Pokemon in Pokemon Go anymore?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274315/4797) should probably be the other way around (this question should be the original).